# How to get the first value of a JSONArray?

Tags: android, json, arrays

My JSON code is as follows:

```
returnString = "";          
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject c = json_data.getJSONObject("data");
            Log.i("log_tag","statues: "+c.getString("statues"));                
            returnString = c.getString("statues"); }
```

Now I want to see the values within my `JSONArray`. The value for statues is either 0 or 1. Further, I will use them in an if else phrase.

What I mean is something like this:

```
if(value of statues = 0){
do something}
else{
do something else}
```

How would I do that?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. For what cases do you want whatever "it" is to be 1?

Comment: Do you mean `if(c.getString("statues").equals("0")) { /* ... */ } else { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 2):

**If you want only first status value in the JSONArray**

to get the first value from JSONArray simply do outside of the loop and before the if statement:

```
JSONObject FirstArray = jArray.getJSONObject(0); // first Array in JSONArray
JSONObject data = FirstData.getString("data");
String FirstStatusValue = data.getString("Status");
```

then parse `FirstStatusValue` to int and use it in if.

I hope I understood your question well, if I didnt please correct me

**if you want all status value within the JSONArray**

before the for loop declare an array of string to and add all the status value in it then loop:

```
String[] StatusArray = new String[jArray.length()]; // will make the status array has the same length as the JSONArray
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject c = json_data.getJSONObject("data");
        Log.i("log_tag","statues: "+c.getString("statues"));
        StatusArray[i] = c.getString("status");
        }
```

then for if statement add for loop then check the statement like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < StatusArray.length(); i++)
{
   if (StatusArray[i] == 0)
      // do something
   else
      // do something

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your concern. Your way is great too.
But a person named @still_learning , has answered it in the best way I wanted.